# Start Transmission in the background

Tags: startup, command-line

Is there a command I can use to start Trasmission in the background?
I added Trasmission to the list of aplications started at startup. Every time after log in the the trasmission window pops up and this is bugging me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Run as

```
transmission --minimized
```

This will launch it minimised to the notification area. For more information check out the man page

```
man transmission
```

For latest Ubuntu use

```
transmission-gtk --minimized
```

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 - this now appears to be `transmission-gtk --minimized`

Answer (score 15):

install this Package: transmission-daemon (and the associated control interface transmission-remote)

$ sudo apt-get install transmission-daemon

So you can start it as a daemon (in the background) and use transmission via browser (transmission-remote)

Ciao.